# Select object from a list o objects by smallest attribute, only if object have neighbours

Tags: scala

As I written in my title, how to get object from a list of objects by smallest attribute **only** if that object have neighbours on the left and right side. If object does not have neighbours select another minimum object. 
My list contains minimum 3 elements.

My input list is:

```
val objects = List(Car("BMW", "Serie 3", 1800), Car("Mercedes", "Benz A", 1400), Car("Audi", "A3", 1200), ...)
```

Car with minimum engine of my list is index 2 `Car("Audi", "A3", 1200)`, which does not have left and right neighbours.
I need choose somehow minimum again to get index 1, which will give me: `Car("Mercedes", "Benz A", 1400)` which has left and right neighbours (index 0 and index2.

I tried this without success, because method can give me any index including first and last object:

```
val cars = List(Car("BMW", "Serie 3", 1800), Car("Mercedes", "Benz A", 1400), Car("Audi", "A3", 1200), ...)
val engines = cars.map(_.engine)
val minEngine = engines.min
// (???) TODO: condition against first and last index to repick min
// which has left and right neighbours
val index = cars.indexWhere(_.engine == minEngine)
println("Previous engine: " cars(index-1) + "Min engine: " + cars(index) + "Next engine: " + cars(index+1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sliding(3)` with `reduce` to get what you want:

```
val minCar = cars.sliding(3).reduce((l, r) => if (r(1).engine > l(1).engine) l else r)(1)
```

This only works for lists of length 3 or more.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the minimum of the list without the first and last element, the remaining cars will have a neighbour.

```
cars.drop(1).dropRight(1).minBy(_.engine)
// or
cars.tail.init.minBy(_.engine)
```

Comment: @LXSoft Now you have specified in your question that you also need the neighbours of the car with the smallest engine, the other anser is more convenient, since you get the three cars in one step.